# Using data connections in Visual Studio to explore SQL Server Express database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am using Entity Framework in order to create my models, but when I try to access the database from the *data connections* in Server Explorer, it does not work. I know the models are being created in the SQL Server Express instance running on my local machine, as I navigated to

```
Computer -> Program Files -> Microsoft SQL Server -> MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS -> MSSQL -> DATA ->
```

and the database is in there.

[image]

Shouldn't my local instance of SQL Server Express show up in this window?

[image]

[I read over this article from Microsoft which explains where database is stored.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under server name type in `\\\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` (assuming you have installed the instance with default values)

then you should be able to access the database from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

you need to select your machine name from the `Server Name` dropdown as shown in below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if your server is not showing in the list then simply open SQL Server note down that `Server Name` and write it Manually.

**Here is an Example**

[image]

[image]